# How to reduce MATLAB serial port transmit delay

Tags: serial-port, port, response, rs485

I'm writing an application to read blocks of data from an external device over an RS485 half duplex link running at 921600 baud. The external device sends a block of data and then the MATLAB app needs to send a short acknowledge response before the device will send the next block. I find that MATLAB takes a varying time, often in excess of 35mS, after reading in the data block before it transmits the acknowledgement back. Is there some way to speed up this apparent serial port transmit delay as this is slowing the interaction down a lot? I am using MATLAB version R2018b. Thanks.

Comment: How are you measuring this delay?

Comment: I have a logic analyzer hooked onto the RS485 lines and can see the data bytes passing back and forth. My first thought was that the delay was due to Windows 10 attending to other processes in the background, but the variation in delay feels too large for that - sometimes 4mS, sometimes 40mS.